# How do I express these group-theory concepts in spoken German?

Tags: mathematics, nomenclature

I'm always having trouble talking about my mathematics in spoken German. For instance:

> `ℤ/nℤ` ("the cyclic group "z over n z" or "z mod n z")
>
> `(ℤ/pℤ)×` (the group non-zero elements of "z over p z")

And a more complex example related to field theory:

> `(ℤ/2ℤ)[T]/(T³+T+1)` ("z mod two-z t – over t cubed plus t plus one", I guess..)

It would be even better if there was a glossary of some kind, telling me how to talk about these things. Still, my question: how do I talk about groups in spoken German?

Comment: If that's how you talk about mathematics in English, then you will have trouble being understood in any language.

Comment: @MartyGreen: Would be nice to explain a bit more clearly, if that's how you leave comment everywhere then you will have trouble being understood in any website!

Comment: I found an interesting website, [Aussprache mathematischer Symbole und Formeln auf Deutsch und Spanisch](http://www.tutz.ws/Uebersetzungen/Mathematik.html).

Comment: Stefano, I didn't mean to criticize your English! I was answering you as though you were a native English speaker, and I was indeed criticizing the way you talked about mathematics. I am also a mathematician and it drives me crazy the way we use specialized jargon to talk about concepts that really should be spoken of in a more descriptive way. It's a problem I think we need to address in whatever language we are speaking. I'm sorry if I criticized you as an Italian who is doing a very good job of speaking English (much better than my Italian) because that was not myu intention.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Marty, I got your point now. :) In an answer, I'd be very happy with a less formal way of saying these things as well, as long as it's understood properly.

Comment: @Gigili The link is good, but as always not enough. For example, what does the sum from 1 to n in different languages? Does it run, carry, go, hop, stretch?

Comment: @MartyGreen I don't think you should have expressed your critique in this unhelpful form. Someone with an Italian name is a *student* in Germany where he learns mathematical terms in a non-native language. It would have been very useful if you had proposed some concrete ways of expressing things differently instead of just complaining about it. I agree that people often mistakenly blame the language barrier for a basic communication problem, but if you think it needs to be addressed, please actually address it. Write an English answer about the underlying problem, someone can then translate.

Comment: @StefanoPalazzo You can learn much more by asking about whole sentences instead of isolated symbols.

Comment: @Phira: Yes unfortunately it doesn't include everything, but at least it's reliable. ("as always" means links are incomplete or I always send something incomplete?)

Comment: @Gigili "As always" = as always in compilations of mathematical language. I am quite frustrated with this myself. It is not enough to know a single phrase for each object to teach or give a good talk in another language. Sorry for the possible negative interpretation. I meant it when I said that it is a good link.

Comment: @Phira: Yes you're right, thank you for the reply.

Comment: If I remember correctly, most of the group theory originated in Germany itself right? I remember Noether as well as words like "eigenvectors". And if it is indeed the case, you can just pick up their original papers to read! :D

Answer (score 5):

I would say:

> Z modulo n.

In most contexts it will be unnecessary to mention Z here.

> Die multiplikative Gruppe modulo p.
>
> Die Polynome (mit Koeffizienten) modulo 2 in der Variable T modulo (dem Polynom) T hoch 3 plus T plus 1.

Note that one never says "T drei" for "T hoch drei" in German, but one can also say "T zur dritten".

Now, if I would have to *dictate* this stuff, I would say something like

> Z modulo n Z.
>
> Z modulo p Z, das ganze in Klammern, hoch dem Kreuzchen für die multiplikative Gruppe.
>
> Z modulo 2 Z in Klammern von in eckigen Klammern T modulo in runden Klammern T hoch 3 plus T plus 1.

While no one speaks like this in a talk or a lecture (well, or no one should), it is important to know because it can be used in case of misunderstandings to point out that someone overlooked a parenthesis.

Comment: Excellent stuff, this is pretty much what I was looking for.

Comment: +1 for "T hoch drei".